# How can I use Bootstrap navbar in ngx-bootstrap for Angular 5?

Tags: angular, navbar, ngx-bootstrap

Bootstrap navbar doesn't exist in the ngx-bootstrap components list. Please help me to implement it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There's no implementation of navbar as a separate component but it can be done with Collapse Module.

Example = https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-rc8ab4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

MODULE

```
// App imports
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, CollapseModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

TS (excerpt)

```
export class AppComponent  {
  isCollapsed = true;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [collapse]="isCollapsed">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I've tried to do this with bootstrap 4, but so far unsuccessful https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-startup-proj

Comment: It works. If someone tries it: just remember you have to import `CollapseModule` in `app.module.ts` to use `collapse` directive.

Comment: One thing this loses is the animation as it opens, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: this looks perfect, but what changes would be needed to use with bootstrap 4?

Comment: Look at the bottom here for bootstrap 4.  Not my answer, but it worked.  https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/540#issuecomment-272884775

Comment: how to animate the collapse/uncollapse? i am unable to figure out.

Comment: You can animate this by setting isAnimated to true. `[collapse]="isCollapsed" [isAnimated]="true"`

Answer (score 1):

In Angular V7 with the following config

```
    Angular CLI: 7.2.2
    Node: 10.14.1
    OS: win32 x64
    Angular: 7.2.1
```

Thanks @llyaSurmay Really a good example. My case was slightly different without collapsible module also using feature module just like below

[image]

If you are using feature module then you need to add your dropdownmodule imports there as well
[image]

Hope it helps someone who is trying to implement the ngx-bootstrap dropdown module in to the navbar. Thanks