# Angular5 and Bootstrap4 - cannot align the last menu item to the right

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5

Similar questions were asked already but there are pretty old and none is actually working for me.
Problem: the last element of the menu do not go right despite applying following styles to it:

1 text-align: right; float: none;
   2 pull-right
   3 float-right

My menu code looks like this:

```
<nav class="nav navbar-toggler">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="../../../assets/banner-1.png">
  </div>
  <h1 class="navbar-text h1">{{ title }}</h1>
</nav>

<nav class="nav nav-header">
  <div class="form-inline container">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link menu-item active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link menu-item" routerLink="/app-registrations-browser">Applications</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link menu-item" routerLink="/users">Users</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link menu-item" routerLink="/inspections">Inspections</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link menu-item" routerLink="/cpe">CPE</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link menu-item" routerLink="/reports">Reports</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link menu-item" routerLink="/help">Help</a>

    <a class="nav-item nav-link" style="color: ghostwhite; text-align: right; float: none;">Logged User</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Are there other ways to force last item to go right?

Answer (score 0):

Angular and Bootstrap navbar don't really work together.
Going off of this guys example, he used nav-right. But he also implemented the navbar using the collapse module.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-anjadq

Source:
[How can I using Bootstrap navbar in ngx-bootstrap for Angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058827/how-can-i-using-bootstrap-navbar-in-ngx-bootstrap-for-angular-5)