# data-toggle is not working in angular 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use the data-toggle functionality to collapse and expand the menu items in the nav bar when the size is medium.   Below is the code I tried to achieve that functionality, but it is not working.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class='row' style='background-color: tomato; padding: 5px'>
          <div class='col-md-12'>
            <app-main-heading></app-main-heading>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class='col-md-12'>
            <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark'>
              <a href='#'></a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/firstmenu">FirstMenu</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/secondmenu">SecondMenu</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/thirdmenu">ThirdMenu</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am not able to collapse and expand when I click on the toggle-button on the nav-bar.

Can anyone please help me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49010911/1009922).

Answer (score 3):

While I tried bootstrap 4 navbar in angular 5 project, faced the similar issue. For handling such situation either I have to install dependency of bootstrap like jquery and popper [techiediaries.com](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-bootstrap/). alternative way use [NgBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io), without those two steps,

I found an alternative way to fix the situation.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" (click)="isMenuCollapse = !isMenuCollapse">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class=" navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{'collapse': isMenuCollapse}"  (click)="isMenuCollapse = !isMenuCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I hope this will help you.