# Bootstrap 4 navbar toggler shows menu items but doesn't expand navbar

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, navbar

Right now I have a navbar that is supposed to collapse when the screen gets smaller. It does collapse and the toggle button works as it should, but when I click the toggle button, the navbar will transition and push down to show the menu items, but as soon as it is done pushing down, it goes back up but the menu items stay there and the main content of the page will cover some of the menu items.

[image]

I have spent the last few hours searching for solutions to this but I can't seem to find anything. Anybody have any tips?

navbar.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-transparent shadow-lg                  navbar-static-top">    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>   </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target">   <a routerLink="home"><span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 "></span></a>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
    <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/services">Resume</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/contact">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>   </ul> </div> </nav>
```

navbar.component.css

```
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}
.nav a{

    font-size: 1.2em !important;
}
```

Comment: You could take a look at [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). It allows to implement the collapsible navbar in Angular with the `ngbCollapse` directive, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49010911/1009922).

Comment: I did just discover that having my menu items centered is causing the issue. Removing the 'navbar-center' seems to fix the issue although its not fully solving my problem as I would like the have the items centered on the bar.